# Rails 3.2.x - log elapsed request time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, rack

Rails 3.2.X logging mechanism has improved tremendously.

Still, I'm looking for a way to add a prefix of 'elapsed time since request has started' (in milliseconds or a timestamp) before each log item. (Request is identified by uuid)

I figure that I may have to write my own Rack middleware for this, but maybe there's a simpler solution out of the box?

**UPDATE**

I built my own Rack middleware:

```
class RequestElapsedTime
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # Set request start time so it can be used as part of the 'request' context.
    env['REQUEST_START_TIME'] = Time.now

    # Call next middleware component
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

    # return a valid rack response
    [status, headers, response]
  end
end
```

And added the following to application.rb:

```
elapsed_time = lambda do |req|
  req_start_time = req.env['REQUEST_START_TIME']
  return unless req_start_time

  (Time.now - req_start_time) * 1000.0
end

# Add request UUID to logs
config.log_tags = [:uuid, elapsed_time]
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, this outputs the same elapsed time for different logs items in the same request, which leads me to think that it might have to do with the fact that lambda is being evaluated for multiple items at once (Buffered Logging?)...
any idea how to solve this?